# Has there ever been a sequel that has been scrapped and remade after release?

Tags: reception, movie-franchise

There has been a lot of talk recently about The Last Jedi being hated, so much so that there are individuals that want to strike it from Star Wars canon and remake it.

Regardless of what you think of this movie (or the proposition to remake it), I'm wondering if there has ever been a movie in a series that has been completely scrapped from the series canon *after* being released. It seems likely that it hasn't happened in a major series, as that seems like it would be widely known. I'm wondering if a production studio *officially* has removed a movie from series canon after release, possibly due to fan reaction, later discovery that there were significant errors in production, or simply change of mind regarding the writing.

Comment: Do you mean "in starwars"? If not, the starwars tag is misleading. If so, there's really not a lot of movies out there. Seems you could have researched this, yourself.

Answer (score 6):

*Superman Returns* released in 2006 is a direct sequel to *Superman 2* and ignores *Superman 3* and *Superman 4*.

The next *Terminator* movie (scheduled for release in 2019) will ignore the events of all Terminator movies after *Terminator 2* because James Cameron will be involved for the first time since *T2*.

Comment: +1 for Superman Returns, that was exactly what popped into my head too.  Also, hadn't heard about the new Terminator but now I'm excited for it!

Comment: same same Steve- O - + 1 - perfect answer - Superman Returns.Absolutely designed to continue the story while discounting and removing the events of 3 & 4TQFP which were of course problematic although 3 at least retains the dignity of the fantastic film-making of the first 2, where as 4 is so awful it still upsets me to this day. I watched the first 2 last week and it was only towards the end of the second film that I realised it was the first time I had watched Margo and Christopher since they both died. Couldn't stop crying through to the end of the film after that ;-(

Answer (score 1):

The new *Halloween* movie coming out in 2018 will [ignore all of the sequels](https://screenrant.com/halloween-reboot-story-details-jamie-lee-curtis/), writing them off as no longer canon.